# systemctl command doesn't work inside docker-container

Tags: docker, service, docker-compose, dockerfile, systemctl

I've made a Docker image for my spring boot application. I'm unable to run systemctl command inside the Docker container. This is what I get when I execute

`systemctl daemon reload` :-

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

Steps I followed to build the Docker image :-

1) `docker build --rm -t <IMAGE_NAME> .`

2) `docker-compose up`

3) `docker exec -it <CONTAINER_NAME> bash`

When I start a service using :-

`service <SERVICE_NAME> start`

I get unrecognised service. How do I execute a service inside docker?

Comment: You don't.  Generally you should assume commands like `systemctl` or `service` just don't work in Docker.  If you're running one process, make it be the main foreground process; if you're running multiple processes, run them in multiple containers.

Comment: @DavidMaze Can you explain with an example if you don't mind

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reuse your existing systemd service descriptors then you either need to run systemd as the entrypoint, or you can use a wrapper script like the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) which is both a service manager and an init daemon.

Comment: Could you explain how to branch it with docker-compose file please

Comment: That's dockerfile where your example is quite correct. Have a look at the examples as well = https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-images

Answer (score 1):

As David commented, you generally don't use process managers like `systemctl` in a docker environment. Instead, you can make your application the primary entry point of the image. See more in the Spring documentation about using it with docker at https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/#_containerize_it.

Key is having something like this in your dockerfile, instead of `systemctl daemon reload`

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```